# Warning Message at Dialog box "JavaScript Window" in PDF Box

Tags: adobe, pdfbox

I have one PDF page on which one Dialog box is opened through that dialog box I will perform some operation.(On click to dialog box one request is generated).

On PDF that Dialog box shows warning:JavaScript Window.

- Pdfbox-2.0.9
- Adobe Reader

Please suggests, How can I removed that warning.
[image]

Comment: please include the code that you used, the PDFBox version, and link to the PDF. Also explain what you mean with "While preparing Dialog box", and what you mean with "one Dialog box created through that dialog box". Did a dialogbox create a dialogbox? Where is that dialogbox? In the PDF, or in a tool? Maybe edit your question to clarify all this.

Comment: *"it shows warning:JavaScript Window. - pdfbox - Adobe Reader"* - does this mean that "pdfbox" is part of the warning text?

Comment: Updated Question, Please check. Sorry for code I can't shared due to some Security reasons. 

for Sample things  https://www.tutorialspoint.com/pdfbox/pdfbox_quick_guide.htm

In above link refer AddJavaScript.java. they prepare code and open Popup and in same Popup Waring occurs.

Comment: I would assume that this is a security measure of the Adobe Reader to warn the user that the dialog is a custom one generated by JavaScript in the PDF and not a genuine Adobe Reader let alone operating system one. In that case you either cannot suppress it or can only do so by signing the document with a very high trust signature or some similar trust producing operation. ([This page](https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-to-remove-Warning-Javascript-Window-q209693.aspx) appears to suggest so.) As you share neither code nor example PDF, that's as much as I can say.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I got two solutions 
 1) using Java Scripts (but as per discussion we don't need to used it )
https://answers.acrobatusers.com/How-to-remove-Warning-Javascript-Window-q209693.aspx
2) Using Digital Signature, I followed below URL but it is not working  
https://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/pdfbox/trunk/examples/src/main/java/org/apache/pdfbox/examples/signature/

If PDF is trusted then it will be remove warning.
Please suggest.